# ¿Cómo se traduciría el término "cousin primes" al castellano?

Tags: traducción, matemáticas

Quisiera saber si existe alguna traducción "oficial" del concepto de *cousin primes* ([descripción de Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin_prime)), ya que, intuitivamente, la traducción literal sería *Primos primos*.

Comment: Según los enlaces de la Wikipedia en inglés, tanto en francés como en italiano e incluso en japonés usan la expresión "primos" (de parentesco) para referirse a este tipo de números primos.

Comment: @carlosAlejo sí, de ahí mi duda. ¿Primos primos?

Comment: Curiosamente en la Wikipedia en español está la entrada de los [primos gemelos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmeros_primos_gemelos) y de los [primos sexis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_primo_sexy) (que difieren en seis), pero no la de los primos primos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si será oficial, pero en muchos artículos por Internet se puede encontrar la expresión "números primos primos".

- [Números primos gemelos y demás familia](http://gaussianos.com/numeros-primos-gemelos-y-demas-familia/).
- [Modelos Probabilísticos de la Distribución de Números Primos. Proceso de Bertrand.](https://ireneses.wordpress.com/2013/06/02/modelos-probabilisticos-de-la-distribucion-de-numeros-primos-el-proceso-de-bertrand/)
- [El amor tiene dos caras](http://lacienciadelcine.blogspot.com.es/2011/02/el-amor-tiene-dos-caras.html) (sí, es una reseña de una peli en la que resulta que el protagonista está obsesionado con los números primos).

No he llegado a encontrar la expresión en ningún texto más oficial. En todo caso, desconozco la importancia matemática de los números primos primos, por lo que ignoro si se suelen comentar en libros.

Comment: De entre los primos interesantes, estos no son especialmente relevantes. ¡Buena búsqueda!